# UIImagePickerController Live Photo

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller, ios10

I'm trying to display a UIImagePickerController that allows users to select either a UIImage or a PHLivePhoto.

```
import Photos

var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.photoLibrary) {

     imagePicker.delegate = self
     imagePicker.sourceType = .savedPhotosAlbum

     imagePicker.mediaTypes = ["kUTTypeImage","kUTTypeLivePhoto"]
}
```

When displaying the view controller, I get the following error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'No available types for source 2'

Comment: Do you want the selected Live Photo to return a `mediaType` of `kUTTypeImage`, `kUTTypeLivePhoto` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So kUTTypeLivePhoto is only available from ios 9.1 and above so you should probably consider putting a version check. Also if you

```
import MobileCoreServices
```

you can use kUTTypeLivePhoto and kUTTypeImage directly.

```
if #available(iOS 9.1, *) {
    picker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeLivePhoto as String, kUTTypeImage as String
} else {
    picker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeImage as String];
};
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: If you don't import, then you would get `code.swift:141:49: Use of unresolved identifier 'kUTTypeLivePhoto'` If I use the code you provide, then I get the error in the question. (I'm on Xcode 10.1)

Answer (score 0):

```
 var imag:UIImagePickerController?

     print("Camera")
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera){
            print("Button capture")
            self.imag = UIImagePickerController()
            self.imag!.delegate = self
            self.imag!.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
            self.imag!.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDevice.Front
            self.imag!.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeImage as String]
            self.imag!.allowsEditing = false
            self.presentViewController(self.imag!, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        print("Gallery")
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary){
            print("Button capture")
            self.imag = UIImagePickerController()
            self.imag!.delegate = self
            self.imag!.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary;
            //imag.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeImage];
            self.imag!.allowsEditing = false
            self.presentViewController(self.imag!, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

  func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
   }
```

Comment: This lets the media browser see the Live Photos in the Photo library, but does it do what the question asks? I commented in question to get clarification.